# Microsoft OCR Library

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ocr, microsoft-ocr

I have recently started to use the Microsoft OCR Library for loading text from images. And I have a question. Is it possible to automatically detect the language of the picture? Or I need set all possible languages by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK,MS OCR lib cannot detect the language of image/pic.
If you need the languages compatibility, you can include all language that your app support in the OCR resource file.